# How to find AR,MA,ARIMA.ARMA,SARIMA,SARMA of a time series data in r

Tags: r, time-series, forecasting, arima, sarimax

```r
library(readxl)
export1 <- read_excel("C:/Users/Hazeeb/OneDrive/Desktop/data/export1.xlsx")

View(export1)

class(export1)
#> [1] "tbl_df"     "tbl"        "data.frame"
#> export1t=ts(export1$`CURRENT TOTAL EXPORT`, frequency = 12, start = c(2007, 1),end = c(2019,12))
#> export1t
#>         Jan    Feb    Mar    Apr    May    Jun    Jul    Aug    Sep
#> 2007  21.97  52.46  53.69  67.32  58.01  53.44  78.83  41.49  37.05
#> 2008  60.26  73.61  51.58  52.95  51.85  86.90  27.57  72.81  42.29
#> 2009  32.80  49.09  53.57  84.30  50.06  46.05  44.04  38.87  47.03
#> 2010  30.46  54.54  48.64  56.41  32.14  48.26  36.17  41.42  39.25
#> 2011  50.17  32.29  45.84  38.02  59.10  46.73  65.44  42.21  64.97
#> 2012  39.99  47.38  77.35  37.34  57.62  46.82  37.32  38.87  75.89
#> 2013  42.36  32.51  88.73  78.91  42.73  55.51  53.42  49.05  82.50
#> 2014 789.81 115.17  39.49  38.70  46.60  33.98  46.87  44.69 406.71
#> 2015  50.74  38.98  41.21  69.58  49.10  46.40  49.03  61.16  91.44
#> 2016  48.08  41.32  50.20  86.05  45.18  60.36  64.85  60.35 187.72
#> 2017 136.71 121.77 152.54 109.91  83.52 120.64 131.19  59.21 110.85
#> 2018 104.66  88.19  98.40  86.78  61.65  61.22  96.28  70.20 107.98
#> 2019  93.99  78.26  57.61  72.30  89.50 138.46  99.57  71.32  81.77
#>         Oct    Nov    Dec
#> 2007  74.55  41.66  32.44
#> 2008 145.88 132.63 136.22
#> 2009  49.55  36.44  43.18
#> 2010  42.14  32.13  46.10
#> 2011  59.12  57.85  67.52
#> 2012  72.72  58.14  37.51
#> 2013  72.06 601.60  43.00
#> 2014  61.96  67.01  54.34
#> 2015  82.08  89.70  71.91
#> 2016 227.43 106.45 100.47
#> 2017 134.85 145.95 118.22
#> 2018 139.42 117.76  99.14
#> 2019 136.79 146.66 197.65
class(export1t)
#> [1] "ts"
library(tseries)
library(forecast)
plot(export1t,xlab="YEAR",ylab="CURRENT TOTAL EXPORT")
#> Error in plot.new() : figure margins too large
plot.ts(export1t,xlab="YEAR",ylab="CURRENT TOTAL EXPORT")
#> Error in plot.new() : figure margins too large
acf(export1t)
#> Error in plot.new() : figure margins too large
pacf(export1t)
#> Error in plot.new() : figure margins too large
```

Answer (score 0):

Your syntax isn't quite right here. When using `ts`, you should set a `frequency` (here 12, to represent months). Then, the `start` argument needs two integers - the starting year and starting month.

You are trying to pass the first item of `DATE` to start, but a) that's not the type of argument `start` takes, b) you didn't have quotes around the character string, and c) even if you did, this is not a date format recognised by R.

You need only do:

```r
ts(export1$`CURRENT TOTAL EXPORT`, frequency = 12, start = c(2007, 1))
#>       Jan  Feb  Mar  Apr  May  Jun  Jul  Aug  Sep  Oct
#> 2007 22.0 52.5 53.7 67.3 58.0 53.4 78.8 41.5 37.0 74.6
```